# Google chrome installation issue in Kali linux 3.20.2

Tags: kali-linux, chrome

I tried to install Google Chrome in Kali linux version 3.20.2, it shows below error. But google chrome is in menu, when i click it it does't shows anything. So Please help me about this...

```
root@RAJAT:~/Downloads# dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 303658 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking google-chrome-stable (55.0.2883.87-1) over (55.0.2883.87-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-chrome-stable:
 google-chrome-stable depends on libappindicator1; however:
  Package libappindicator1 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package google-chrome-stable (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.47) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-8) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable
root@RAJAT:~/Downloads#
```

Answer (score 3):

As clearly shown in the output of `dpkg`, Chrome has not been installed properly because of a failed dependency with package `libappindicator1`. You need either to to install that package first, or try to install Chrome using a high-level package manager such as `apt-get` which automatically solves dependencies with other packages.